# Javascript particles are clipping over the edges

Tags: javascript, particles

I have this small particle script that I adjusted to my liking, but I have one problem.

Once the particles come to the edge, they get clipped a bit (maybe 10 - 15px), is there any padding attribute for canvas that I could use to give them a bit of space?

I've created snippet bellow to show what's the problem if anyone is interested to help out?

```js
let resizeReset = function() {
    w = canvasBody.width = 800;
    h = canvasBody.height = 460;
}

const opts = { 
    particleColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
    lineColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
    particleAmount: 8,
    defaultSpeed: 0.05,
    variantSpeed: 1,
    defaultRadius: 5,
    variantRadius: 10,
    linkRadius: 500,
};

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    deBouncer();
});

let deBouncer = function() {
    clearTimeout(tid);
    tid = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeReset();
    }, delay);
};

let checkDistance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2){ 
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
};

let linkPoints = function(point1, hubs){ 
    for (let i = 0; i < hubs.length; i++) {
        let distance = checkDistance(point1.x, point1.y, hubs[i].x, hubs[i].y);
        let opacity = 1 - distance / opts.linkRadius;
        if (opacity > 0) { 
            drawArea.lineWidth = 0.5;
            drawArea.strokeStyle = `rgba(${rgb[0]}, ${rgb[1]}, ${rgb[2]}, ${opacity})`;
            drawArea.beginPath();
            drawArea.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
            drawArea.lineTo(hubs[i].x, hubs[i].y);
            drawArea.closePath();
            drawArea.stroke();
        }
    }
}

Particle = function(xPos, yPos){ 
    this.x = Math.random() * w; 
    this.y = Math.random() * h;
    this.speed = opts.defaultSpeed + Math.random() * opts.variantSpeed; 
    this.directionAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360); 
    this.color = opts.particleColor;
    this.radius = opts.defaultRadius + Math.random() * opts. variantRadius; 
    this.vector = {
        x: Math.cos(this.directionAngle) * this.speed,
        y: Math.sin(this.directionAngle) * this.speed
    };
    this.update = function(){ 
        this.border(); 
        this.x += this.vector.x; 
        this.y += this.vector.y; 
    };
    this.border = function(){ 
        if (this.x >= w || this.x <= 0) { 
            this.vector.x *= -1;
        }
        if (this.y >= h || this.y <= 0) {
            this.vector.y *= -1;
        }
        if (this.x > w) this.x = w;
        if (this.y > h) this.y = h;
        if (this.x < 0) this.x = 0;
        if (this.y < 0) this.y = 0; 
    };
    this.draw = function(){ 
        drawArea.beginPath();
        drawArea.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        drawArea.closePath();
        drawArea.fillStyle = this.color;
        drawArea.fill();
    };
};

function setup(){ 
    particles = [];
    resizeReset();
    for (let i = 0; i < opts.particleAmount; i++){
        particles.push( new Particle() );
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function loop(){ 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    drawArea.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        particles[i].update();
        particles[i].draw();
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        linkPoints(particles[i], particles);
    }
}

const canvasBody = document.getElementById("canvas"),
drawArea = canvasBody.getContext("2d");
let delay = 200, tid,
rgb = opts.lineColor.match(/\d+/g);
resizeReset();
setup();
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  margin: 0rem;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#canvas {
  // position: absolute;
  display: block;
  // top: 0;
  // left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think you're checking the centre of the "dot" to see if it's hit the edge. If so, you need to add the radius to the "dot" to see if it's hit the edge.

Comment: It looks like you are detecting the collision based on the center of the circle rather than the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Add the radius to the position on the edge detection

However I found a problem : if a circle start in an edge, it don't seems to move.

```js
let resizeReset = function() {
    w = canvasBody.width = 800;
    h = canvasBody.height = 460;
}

const opts = { 
    particleColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
    lineColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
    particleAmount: 8,
    defaultSpeed: 0.05,
    variantSpeed: 1,
    defaultRadius: 5,
    variantRadius: 10,
    linkRadius: 500,
};

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    deBouncer();
});

let deBouncer = function() {
    clearTimeout(tid);
    tid = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeReset();
    }, delay);
};

let checkDistance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2){ 
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
};

let linkPoints = function(point1, hubs){ 
    for (let i = 0; i < hubs.length; i++) {
        let distance = checkDistance(point1.x, point1.y, hubs[i].x, hubs[i].y);
        let opacity = 1 - distance / opts.linkRadius;
        if (opacity > 0) { 
            drawArea.lineWidth = 0.5;
            drawArea.strokeStyle = `rgba(${rgb[0]}, ${rgb[1]}, ${rgb[2]}, ${opacity})`;
            drawArea.beginPath();
            drawArea.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
            drawArea.lineTo(hubs[i].x, hubs[i].y);
            drawArea.closePath();
            drawArea.stroke();
        }
    }
}

Particle = function(xPos, yPos){ 
    this.x = Math.random() * w; 
    this.y = Math.random() * h;
    this.speed = opts.defaultSpeed + Math.random() * opts.variantSpeed; 
    this.directionAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360); 
    this.color = opts.particleColor;
    this.radius = opts.defaultRadius + Math.random() * opts. variantRadius; 
    this.vector = {
        x: Math.cos(this.directionAngle) * this.speed,
        y: Math.sin(this.directionAngle) * this.speed
    };
    this.update = function(){ 
        this.border(); 
        this.x += this.vector.x; 
        this.y += this.vector.y; 
    };
    this.border = function(){ 
        if (this.x + this.radius >= w || this.x - this.radius<= 0) { // Changes here
            this.vector.x *= -1;
        }
        if (this.y + this.radius >= h || this.y - this.radius <= 0) { // And here
            this.vector.y *= -1;
        }
        if (this.x > w) this.x = w;
        if (this.y > h) this.y = h;
        if (this.x < 0) this.x = 0;
        if (this.y < 0) this.y = 0; 
    };
    this.draw = function(){ 
        drawArea.beginPath();
        drawArea.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        drawArea.closePath();
        drawArea.fillStyle = this.color;
        drawArea.fill();
    };
};

function setup(){ 
    particles = [];
    resizeReset();
    for (let i = 0; i < opts.particleAmount; i++){
        particles.push( new Particle() );
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function loop(){ 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    drawArea.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        particles[i].update();
        particles[i].draw();
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        linkPoints(particles[i], particles);
    }
}

const canvasBody = document.getElementById("canvas"),
drawArea = canvasBody.getContext("2d");
let delay = 200, tid,
rgb = opts.lineColor.match(/\d+/g);
resizeReset();
setup();
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  margin: 0rem;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#canvas {
  // position: absolute;
  display: block;
  // top: 0;
  // left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 80%;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to investigate further and see if I can move it away from the edge at the start.